# How to insert all json file data in database?

Tags: laravel

I have JSON file and have data in it. I want to import all data in the database through DB seeders. I am getting an error `Trying to get property name of non-object`. I have multiple data how I can insert in the database?

```
public function run()
{
    $json = File::get("public/kmz/WASASubdivisions.geojson");
    $data = json_decode($json);
 //        dd($data);
    foreach ($data as $obj){
        Regions::create(array(
            'name' => $obj[0]->Name,
            'description' => $obj[0]->description,
            'altitudeMode' => $obj[0]->altitudeMode,
            'Town' => $obj[0]->Town,
            'AC' => $obj[0]->AC,
            'No_of_TW' => $obj[0]->No_of_TW,
            'No' => $obj[0]->No,
            'DC'=> $obj[0]->DC,
            'HH_2017' => $obj[0]->HH_2017,
            'FID' => $obj[0]->FID,
            'Area_ha' => $obj[0]->Area_ha,
            'Field_1' => $obj[0]->Field_1,
            'Pop_Dens' => $obj[0]->Pop_Dens,
            'Id' => $obj[0]->Id,
            'Pop_2017' => $obj[0]->Pop_2017,
            'Area_Sq'=> $obj[0]->Area_Sq,
        ));
    }
}
```

Sample Json Format

```
31 => {#837
  +"type": "Feature"
  +"properties": {#838
    +"Name": "Gujjar Pura"
    +"description": null
    +"altitudeMode": "clampToGround"
    +"Town": "Shalimar Town"
    +"AC": "31"
    +"No_of_TW": "11"
    +"No": "13"
    +"DC": "38"
    +"HH_2017": "30478"
    +"FID": "31"
    +"Area_ha": "648.327"
    +"Field_1": "Gujjar Pura"
    +"Pop_Dens": "54063.141167"
    +"Id": "0"
    +"Pop_2017": "196619"
    +"Area_Sq": "3.63684"
  }
  +"geometry": {#839
    +"type": "MultiPolygon"
    +"coordinates": array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        0 => array:169 [ …169]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you using $obj[0] ? just put $obj->Name

Comment: I have tried still getting Trying to get property name of non object

Comment: Are you sure data format is correct.

Comment: yes i have 34 objects

Answer (score 0):

**since i am not a big fan of processing the json as a object**

So the `json_decode` will accept the second arg so

```
$json = File::get("public/kmz/WASASubdivisions.geojson");
$data = json_decode($json,true);

dd($data);

foreach ($data as $obj)
    {
    Regions::create(array(
            'name' => $obj['Name'],
    'description' => $obj['description'],
    'altitudeMode' => $obj['altitudeMode'],
    'Town' => $obj['Town'],
    'AC' => $obj['AC'],
    'No_of_TW' => $obj['No_of_TW'],
    'No' => $obj['No'],
    'DC'=> $obj['DC'],
    'HH_2017' => $obj['HH_2017'],
    'FID' => $obj['FID'],
    'Area_ha' => $obj['Area_ha'],
    'Field_1' => $obj['Field_1'],
    'Pop_Dens' => $obj['Pop_Dens'],
    'Id' => $obj['Id'],
    'Pop_2017' => $obj['Pop_2017'],
    'Area_Sq'=> $obj['Area_Sq'],
        ));
    }
```

Can You Post the **dd()** result and fileds sets of the table

Comment: I already posted it.. I have 34 objects and have big data in it

Comment: `json_decode($jsonData,true)` will give give you array not the objet

Comment: check now i have answered

Comment: can you share some sample json in the Question

Answer (score 0):

```
public function run()
{
    $json = File::get("public/kmz/WASASubdivisions.geojson");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    dd($data);
    foreach ($data as $obj){
        Regions::create(array(
            'name' => $obj->Name,
            'description' => $obj->description,
            'altitudeMode' => $obj->altitudeMode,
            'Town' => $obj->Town,
            'AC' => $obj->AC,
            'No_of_TW' => $obj->No_of_TW,
            'No' => $obj->No,
            'DC'=> $obj->DC,
            'HH_2017' => $obj->HH_2017,
            'FID' => $obj->FID,
            'Area_ha' => $obj->Area_ha,
            'Field_1' => $obj->Field_1,
            'Pop_Dens' => $obj->Pop_Dens,
            'Id' => $obj->Id,
            'Pop_2017' => $obj->Pop_2017,
            'Area_Sq'=> $obj->Area_Sq,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's support I have a model `Post` and I want to save additional data in JSON format in the posts table. In that case, we can use property `$casts` in Laravel. Which will cast our field value to whatever we gave.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table='posts';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'short_description', 'description', 'status', 'json_data'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'json_data' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Now we want to save data something like this

```
$data = [
    'user_id' => 1,
    'title' => 'abc',
    'short_description' => 'test',
    'description' => 'test',
    'status' => true,
    'json_data' => [
        'additional_info' => '',
        'post_image' => '',
        ...
    ],
];

$item = new Post;
$item->fill($data)->save();
```

This will save your `json_data` array values to JSON in the database. But when you will get data from the database it will convert that to array automatically.

For reference read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are under the `properties` key, but you're referencing them from the root of the object. e.g. `$obj[0]->Name` should be `$obj[0]->properties->Name`, etc.

Comment: trying to get property properties of non-object error